# C++ references and modification

Tags: c++

Lets say I have

```
void swap(int &x, int &y){
  //do swap here
 }
```

Why is it legal to do: `x = y` inside of the function so that **it assigns the VALUE of** `y` to `x`?

Why isn't some sort of dereferencing needed?

Comment: perhaps you should take a good book on C++ (or a good web tutorial) and learn about references?

Comment: This should be covered near the beginning of your C++ textbook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)

Comment: You can think of references as pointers that automatically dereference (that's essentially what's happening behind the scenes).

Answer (score 6):

There's no dereferencing needed since references are *not* pointers. They are aliases to the referenced object.

Comment: "variable" -> "object" </pedantic> :)